# Submit do form não esta direcionando e rapassando o valor para o arquivo php

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Estou com um probleminha aqui com o repasse ao clicar no submit era para repassar para outro arquivo php, os valores vindo de um loop php, testei sem o loop vai... mais buscando os dados do banco do Wordpress não vai alguem tem alguma sugestão?

```js
  <script>
        total = 0;
        
        function adiciona(id)
        {
            calcula(id,"adicao");
        }
        
        function remove(id)
        {
            calcula(id,"subtracao");
        }    
            
        function calcula(id,operacao)
        {
                nomeid  = "nome"+id;
                precoid = "preco"+id;
                qtdid   = "qtd"+id;
                
                nome  = document.getElementById(nomeid).innerHTML;
                
                preco = document.getElementById(precoid).innerHTML;    
                preco = parseInt(preco);
                
                qtd   = document.getElementById(qtdid).innerHTML;
                qtd   = parseInt(qtd);

                //Debug
                //alert("Produto: " + nome + "\n Preço: " + preco);    
                
                if(operacao=="adicao")
                {
                    total = total + preco;
                    qtd = qtd + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    total = total - preco;
                    qtd = qtd - 1;
                }
                
                document.getElementById(qtdid).innerHTML = qtd;
                
                document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
        }    
            
        
    </script>
  
  
  
   <!-- REPASSA PARA O PHP -->         

  
  
  
  
  <script>
   function verifica_e_envia()
   {
    array_dados = new Array();
   
    colecao = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    
    qtd_blocos = colecao.length - 1; // O último tr da tabela é onde fica o total e está sendo descontado
    // É necessário saber a quantidade de blocos para poder usar em um loop catando os valores
    
    // Percorre os blocos catando nomes, quantidades e valores dos produtos com quantidade maior que zero
    for(i=1; i<=qtd_blocos ;i++)
    {
     qtdid = "qtd"+i;
     qtd   = document.getElementById(qtdid).innerHTML;
     qtd   = parseInt(qtd);
     
     if(qtd>0)
     {
      obj_tmp = {};
      
      nomeid = "nome"+i;
      nome   = document.getElementById(nomeid).innerHTML;
      
      precoid = "preco"+i;
      preco   = document.getElementById(precoid).innerHTML;
      preco   = parseInt(preco);

      obj_tmp.nome  = nome;
      obj_tmp.preco = preco;
      obj_tmp.qtd   = qtd;
      obj_tmp.subtotal = qtd*preco;
      
      // adiciona elemento no array de dados que será enviado
      array_dados.push(obj_tmp);
     }
    }
    
    // põe o array_dados no input hidden json_dados
    document.getElementById("json_dados").value = JSON.stringify(array_dados);
    
    // envia o formulário form_pedido_produtos
    document.getElementById("form_pedido_produtos").submit();

   }
  </script>
```

```html
  <table>
  
    <!-- INICIA Bloco gerado por LOOP PHP -->
  
  
 <?php query_posts('showposts=2category_name=gas');?>

<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
                       
   
    
        <tr>
            <td class="prodtd">

                <div id="nome<?php the_id(); ?>"  class="nomeprod"> <?php the_title(); ?></div>

                <div id="preco<?php the_id(); ?>" class="preco"><?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'preco', true ); ?></div>

            </td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle">

                <input type="button" value="-" onclick="remove(<?php the_id(); ?>)"> 

                <span id="qtd<?php the_id(); ?>">0</span> 

                <input type="button" value="+" onclick="adiciona(<?php the_id(); ?>)">

            </td>
        </tr>
      
            
<?php endwhile; else:?>
<?php endif;?>
            
 <!-- FINALIZA Bloco gerado por LOOP PHP -->         
           
            
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><b>Total: <span id="total">0<span></b></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            
        </table>
        
  
  
    
  
  <form action="http://localhost/soma_total/pedido_produtos.php" method="post" id="form_pedido_produtos">
   <input type="hidden" name="json_dados" id="json_dados">  
   <input type="button" value="Verifica e envia valores" onclick="verifica_e_envia()">
  </form>
```

Comment: Em vez de utilizar um input `type="button"`, tenta `type="submit"`. Nesse caso você removeria o evento `onclick` do input e incluiria no form, só que como `onsubmit`. Dessa forma você não precisa forçar via JavaScript, e pode cancelar o evento com um simples `return false;` caso os dados sejam inválidos.

Comment: No caso assim <input type="submit" value="Verifica e envia valores" onsubmit="verifica_e_envia()">

Comment: Não, assim: `<form action="http://localhost/soma_total/pedido_produtos.php" method="post" id="form_pedido_produtos" onsubmit="verifica_e_envia()">`

Comment: <form action="http://localhost/soma_total/pedido_produtos.php" method="post" id="form_pedido_produtos">
   <input type="hidden" name="json_dados" id="json_dados">  
   <input type="button" value="Verifica e envia valores" onclick="verifica_e_envia()">
  </form>

Comment: Da esse erro Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Comment: Hemerson, na sua tag form que vc escreveu no comentário acima tem um ponto e vírgula (;) perdido dentro da tag.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Outra coisa:
Essa função the_id(); já tem um echo dentro dela ou é um return do conteúdo? Se for apenas um return, use echo the_id();

Comment: Esse é um erro de PHP, então parabéns, você conseguiu postar os dados. Agora é outro problema.

Comment: ja vem a identificação do post quando adiciono ela dentro do loop

Comment: Cara acho que sei o que está acontecendo. Vou pôr numa resposta pq aqui como comentário o código fica todo espremido.

Comment: Quando eu coloco <input type="submit" value="Verifica e envia valores" onclick="verifica_e_envia()"> vai mais sem os valores

Comment: Quando eu coloco action=final.php da esse erro Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in quando eu nao coloco vai mais sem os valores

Comment: Dá uma olhada nessa resposta abaixo agora.
Está com os números que são concatenados com os nomes dos ids de html começando por 1 e sendo incrementados. Esses ids só servem pro javascript achar eles e enviar os dados. Se puser ids do seu banco ele não vai seguir aquela ordem do for de javascript certinho.

Answer (score 0):

Cara acho que sei o que está acontecendo.

Tenta o seguinte, ao invés de usar essa função the_id(), cria um uma variavel $i começando de $i = 1;  e dentro do loop vc põe $i++;

Ficará o seguinte:

```
<?php 
$i=1;   // $i começando com 1 aqui
if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>     

        <tr>
            <td class="prodtd">

                <div id="nome<?php echo $i; ?>"  class="nomeprod"> <?php the_title(); ?></div>

                <div id="preco<?php echo $i; ?>" class="preco"><?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'preco', true ); ?></div>

            </td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle">

                <input type="button" value="-" onclick="remove(<?php echo $i; ?>)"> 

                <span id="qtd<?php echo $i; ?>">0</span> 

                <input type="button" value="+" onclick="adiciona(<?php echo $i; ?>)">

            </td>
        </tr>

<?php $i++; ?>


<?php endwhile; else:?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Explicação:
Teu javascript está procurando esses "ids" e tá confiando que eles são sequenciais (sei disso pq ajudei com esse código numa outra pergunta sua, hahaha). Mas eles só servem pra ajudar a catar os dados da página, não tem que ser ids de banco, como é o que tá acontecendo aí. 
Dá uma verificada por favor e diga se assim resolve.

Comment: Quando eu coloco isso  action="http://localhost/souza/wordpress/index.php" da esse erro Invalid argument supplied for foreach() quando tiro o index.php vai mais nao vai os valores aparece post nao pode ser enviado

Comment: Vamos pro chat rsrsrs

Comment: Vamos sim! hahaha

Comment: Acho que só aparece o link do chat quando já tem um monte de comentário aqui... Vai no chat do outro tópico, mas deixa essa aba aberta.